# Animate.css animation not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I'm currently using the [Animate.css](https://daneden.me/animate/) Framework. I'm looking to make a little bar that I've create to simply move a few pixels up the page when every I hover over an image. Here is the code for the image and the small bar:

```
<div id="GoogleBar" class="bar"  style="position:fixed;bottom:5%;left:33.8%;">
    <center>Google +</center>
</div>
<a href="http://www.google.com"><img id="Google" src="css/images/Google_PlusBook.png" style="width:5.9%;height:15%;position:fixed;bottom:3.2%;left:33.2%;padding:4px;"></a>
```

The Css for the bar:

```
.bar
{
    background: #000000;
    width: 5%;
    height: 3%;
    color:#ffffff;
    line-height: 150%;
    border:1px solid #ffffff;
    border-radius:25px;     
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

Here is the code I am using to add the animation classes to when ever I hover over the image:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
        {     
            $('#Google').hover(function()
            {     
                $('#GoogleBar').removeClass('animated bounceInDown');
                $('#GoogleBar').addClass('animated bounceInUp');  
            },     
            function()
            {    
                $('#GoogleBar').removeClass('animated bounceInUp');  
                $('#GoogleBar').addClass('animated bounceInDown');    
            });
        });
```

Now I know the class is being added to the bar, as I have inspected it in the browser but for some reason the bar isn't moving up and down the screen. I'm really not sure why its not working

Comment: Mind creating a fiddle for this?

Comment: maybe position fixed creates a conflict, try remove this from animated element.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setTimeout()` function because i think u are adding and removing the classes at the same time resulting in the effect not having the time to take effect. :

```
$(document).ready(function() 
        {     
            $('#Google').mouseenter(function()
            {     
                $('#GoogleBar').removeClass('animated bounceInDown');
                $('#GoogleBar').addClass('animated bounceInUp');  

                setTimeout(function() {
                   $('#GoogleBar').removeClass('animated bounceInUp');  
                   $('#GoogleBar').addClass('animated bounceInDown'); 
                },1000);
            });
        });
```

Else you can add `mouseout()` handler to change the classes after u have added them in `mousenter()`.